# Reportviewer(RDLC) Repeat header on each page not working when exporting to MS word

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

Reportviewer(RDLC)I setup a report to show headerRow on each page.  when Export the report in pdf i can see headerRow on each page, but when export the same report in microsoft word header is only on page1 all other pages are without headerRow.
There are some limitation of exporting into word i can see here ..
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627455(v=sql.100).aspx

Any Idea how to repeat headerrow in word on each page??

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from the page you linked to (emphasis is mine):

> Word does not repeat header rows on pages two and later although you
>   set the RepeatOnNewPage property of the static header row in a tablix
>   (table, matrix, or list) to true. **You can define explicit page breaks
>   into your report to force header rows to appear on new pages. However,
>   because Word applies its own pagination to the rendered report
>   exported to Word, results might vary and the header row might not
>   repeat predictably.** The static header row is the row that contains the
>   column headings.

It seems like the only possibility is to define explicit page breaks, but this may not work reliably anyway.